# Falcon Olympic year identification

Tags: vintage

I'm looking to try and identify the year this bike was built. Currently struggling to add photo's. [image]
I will try and add some more in a minute. The frame number of the bike is 14246

Many thanks
Wesley

Comment: If you're struggling with the photos (there are restrictions on new users) you may be able to upload them to imgur and post the links in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Nice bike - from the overall lines of the frame its definitely something from the 80s.

The head tube is relatively short, so I'm guessing this is a smaller frame, maybe a 50cm or less.

The pronounced curve of the front fork became straighter as time went on due to manufacturing changes.  Also the right fork tine has a lamp mount which was common for the time.

The three silver cable clamps on the top tube are more of a 70s design, but they may not be original.

The bike has U brakes rather than cheaper calipers, so its a mid-range bike not a budget bike.  These require a cable stop, so are probably original equipment.

I'm sure the chainrings tell a story too - they have quite a difference between the large and small, in terms of tooth count.

Your rims are interesting - I can't tell if they are steel or aluminium (ie replaced later)

The only damage I can see is the two stays holding the rear of the front mudguard.  Normally they'd be straight, not bent up which suggests something got in the spokes once.  Minor as long as nothing's rubbing.

I suggest you clean that filthy chain and cassette, then relubricate.  That blackness is suspended grit which is slowly grinding away at the components of the transmission.

**I would call this a touring bike from the early 1980s.**  Its not a race bike, but that crankset would help it get up hills when loaded.  The better brakes also help a heavily loaded bike come down the other side.

Overall, looks like a loverly bike and a pleasure to ride.

Comment: Yeah, 80s bike, in a "light touring" configuration.  Bog-standard for the era.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replies. I wanted to upload more photo's but cant seem to get them on here? Other info I can give is the rear derailleur is a shimano crane and the front is shimano 60. Picked it up for £30 which I thought was too good to refuse. The bike is now stripped to the frame and I will disassemble all parts, clean thoroughly and replace any parts that need it. Once done I'll get it sold on. It's just a bit of a hobby really. Cheers again. Wes

Comment: @WesleyGill if you find it comfortable to ride, then keep it.  There's no reason for not owning a range of bikes - its one of the cheaper vices :)

Comment: I would but my misses might disagree. Already have several she wants me to thin out.

Comment: Was thinking possible mid 70's with the derailleur's its running?

Comment: Managed to ID it (as best I can) as a 1976 Olympic model. Got the date from stamp dates (assuming they are original) on the brakes and levers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding information to Criggie's accurate answer.

This is not the same bike but it is an Olympic and the style of decal matches your bike.
Your frame has the wrap around stays and this one does not.

[image]

I don't view an ebay post as authoritative. The add says it's a 1980 - that's possible - but it's also possible that it's more like early 80s as opposed to exactly 1980.

I'm still searching for a catalog or something more authoritative.

[According to the ebay add](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Falcon-Olympic-1980-Designed-by-Ernie-Clements-Classic-Eroica-Britannia-Bicycle/224234243858?hash=item3435670712:g:1Q0AAOSw5otfYLVF):

> Falcon Olympic 1980
> Make: Falcon Cycles
> Model:Olympic designed by Ernie Clements
> Year: 1980
> Size:Seat Tube: C2C 54cm , Top to C BB 55.5cm , Top tube C2C 55cm front to back 58cm
> Tubing: Reynolds 531
> Brakes: Weinmann Vainquer Black Label Centre Pulls
> Brake Levers: Weinmann. Hooded
> Crankset: Sugino Super Maxy - 52 - 42
> Crank Arm length: 165
> Shifters: Shimano 600 Arabesque
> Rear Derailleur: Shimano 600 Arabesque (Long Cage)
> Front Derailleur: Shimano 600 Arabesque
> Freewheel/ Block: Shimano 5 Speed
> Hubs: Mailard Large Flange

Comment: Nice find!   The only differences i can see are the rims are a different profile, and the read brake cable is secured by braze-ons not band-on clamps.   Otherwise its a dead ringer with the same hoods and saddle, cranks etc.

Answer (score 0):

Falccon continued to make high class bikes into the early 80s, the Olympic was a good alternative to something like a Dawes Galaxy - but rode even better, ime.

The one in the pic looks very well used - look at the teeth on the chainrings.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  The question was about identifying the bike; is there anything you can add to the existing answers to improve the identification?  This seems like more of a comment, which shouldn't be posted as an answer; when you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments.  In the meantime you might want to take the [tour].